# Susy columns and breakpoints disorder list?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I'm using Susy and its breakpoints to do some media queries layouts, but I'm having this weird issue where the `<li>` gets all in different order, it's very strange.

Check the cases here (**Warning NSFW**): http://cl.ly/L6Xf and here http://cl.ly/L6cd

```
// Grid
.page
  +container
  +susy-grid-background

// Profiles
#profiles
  ul
    margin-top: 2.5em
    li
      height: 160px
      +span-columns(5)
      &:nth-child(2n)
        +omega         
      margin-bottom: 2.2em
      border: 5px solid $white
      overflow: hidden
      img
        width: auto
        height: 100% 
      span
        background: $white
        padding: 5px 10px
        position: absolute


+at-breakpoint(30em 12)
  #profiles ul li
    +span-columns(4, 12)
    &:nth-child(3n)
      +omega
```

Thanks,

Comment: A NSFW warning might be nice for those images.

Answer (score 1):

At your new breakpoint, you need to remove omega from 2n before adding it to 3n. Otherwise you have omega set on both 2n and 3n `li`s.

```
+at-breakpoint(30em 12)
  #profiles ul li
    +remove-nth-omega(2n)
    +span-columns(4, 12)
    +nth-omega(3n)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the perfect solution!